# How to drop a column from Dictionary, which is assigned to be the key and required to drop it

Tags: python, pandas

```
df_countries = dict(list(df_countries.groupby('Country'))) 
for df in df_countries.values():     
    df.drop('Country', axis=1)

df_countries["Australia"]
```

Above is the coding that I typed, but how to drop the column country?? From the output, the column 'Country' didn't drop

[image: Output 1][image: Output 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the `inplace=True` parameter

```
df_countries = dict(list(df_countries.groupby('Country'))) 
for df in df_countries.values():     
    df.drop('Country', inplace=True, axis=1)

df_countries["Australia"]
```